# How to upgrade ubuntu in side virtual box installed using vagrant?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, virtualbox, vagrant

I have Ubuntu 14 installed to my virtual machine(Virtual Box) using **vagrant**. Now I want to upgrade it to Ubuntu 16.

I have an ISO image of Ubuntu 16 with me. Is it possible to upgrade to latest version using this image or I have to use some other approach.When I go to setting and select usb it is disabled and I am not able to enable it.

[image]

If I run following command `sudo do-release-upgrade` it says no new release found.

Please guide me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

Comment: It was installed using vagrant not directly

Comment: Upgrades between LTS releases are not enabled by default until the first point release, 12.04.1/14.04.1, scheduled for July/August. It is recommended that most LTS users wait until then before upgrading

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the ISO image to the virtual box and the upgrade dialog should pop up. Also you can use the upgrade via Internet (upgrade manager) from within the Virtual Box.

Comment: You might be able to improve this answer with providing the steps needed in more detail and maybe even adding screen-shots of different parts to make it a rock solid answer.